# Swift Dictionary Group first element nil

Tags: swift, dictionary

I write this example in playground to replicate issue

```
    import UIKit


struct test{
    var id: Int
    var nsm: String
}
let datas = [test(id:1, nsm: "test1"), test(id:2,nsm: "test2"),test(id: 3, nsm: "test3")]
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: datas, by: { $0.id})

print(dict[0])
```

if I print "dict[0]" I get "nil" but if I print "dict[1]" I get the first element. Why?

Comment: It is a dictionary. Not an array. There is no first element. You are grouping your items by their id. So dict[1] is returning the items that have been grouped with the id 1. Which happens to be the first item from your array.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the correct and expected answer.

`dict[0]` is not "the first element" of the dictionary. A dictionary has no "first element"; it has no order. You are doing dictionary lookup by *key*. `dict[0]` is the list of all elements of the original array `datas` whose `id` is 0. There are no such elements so there is no such item in the dictionary.

`dict[1]` is the list of all elements of `datas` whose `id` is 1. There is one such element and that is the one that you see as a value.